# transparent gradients with graphicsmagick

Tags: imagemagick, transparency, gradient, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to create a gradient that goes from transparent to some color. With imageMagick you can do that with (taken from the documentation):

```
 convert -size 100x100 gradient:none-firebrick gradient_transparent.png
```

If I try the same command in graphicsMagick, the gradient will go from black to firebrick:

```
gm convert -size 100x100 gradient:none-firebrick gradient_transparent.png
```

How should I (or can I) use graphicsMagick to accomplish this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem described only happens with Q8 versions (QuantumDepth=8): I tried with **GraphicsMagick-1.3.18-Q8**  and obtained a black to firebrick gradient as reported.

Using the same command in **GraphicsMagick-1.3.18-Q16** (QuantumDepth=16) I obtained a transparent to firebrick gradient.

Q8 output:

[image: q8]

Q16 output:

[image: q16]